# How to fix not update UI in socket on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

In my application I used [**Socket.io**](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) and I want when receive listener from socket I should **update UI**.
I write below codes, but **not update my UI**!
For test this i write `Log.e` when receive socket listener, show this `Log`, but **not update UI**!

**My Codes:**

```
@Override
public void onSocketUpdateBid(final JSONObject ob) {
    Log.e("updateBidCount", "Receive");
    super.onSocketUpdateBid(ob);
    final int auction_id;
    final String remainClick;
    final JSONObject data = ob;
    try {
        UpdateBidResponse updateBidResponse = new Gson().fromJson(data.toString(), UpdateBidResponse.class);
        auction_id = updateBidResponse.getAuction_id();
        remainClick = updateBidResponse.getRemain_click();
        Constants.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
            if (detail.getId() != null) {
                Log.e("RemainClickLog", "" + remainClick);
                if (detail.getId().equals(auction_id)) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(remainClick) > 0) {
                        Log.e("updateBidLog", "RemainClick : " + remainClick);
                        auctionDetail_miniBottomBidTxt.setText(remainClick);
                        auctionDetail_footerPlusBidBtn.setAlpha(1.0f);
                        auctionDetail_footerPlusBidBtn.setEnabled(true);
                        auctionDetail_footerPlusBidBtn.setClickable(true);
                        Log.e("updateBidLog", "Enable");
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setEnabled(true);
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setClickable(true);
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setAlpha(1.0f);
                        isShowSendBid = true;
                    } else if (Integer.parseInt(remainClick) == 0) {
                        Log.e("updateBidLog", "Disable");
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setEnabled(false);
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setClickable(false);
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setAlpha(0.4f);
                        auctionDetail_miniBottomBidTxt.setText("0");
                        isNotEndBids = true;
                        isShowSendBid = false;
                    } else {
                        Log.e("updateBidLog", "Disable");
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setEnabled(false);
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setClickable(false);
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setAlpha(0.4f);
                        auctionDetail_miniBottomBidTxt.setText("0");
                        isNotEndBids = true;
                        isShowSendBid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("updateBidCount", "Err : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When run application and receive socket listener i show `Log.e("updateBidLog", "Disable");` into **logcat tab**.
But not run this code :

```
auctionDetail_footerBottom.setEnabled(false);
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setClickable(false);
                        auctionDetail_footerBottom.setAlpha(0.4f);
                        auctionDetail_miniBottomBidTxt.setText("0");
                        isNotEndBids = true;
                        isShowSendBid = false;
```

and not update UI !

**Update :** I used this `Constants.currentActivity.runOnUiThread` for update UI. but not update UI!

How can i fix it?

Comment: Is there any error that you are getting into the logcat?

Comment: @Sunny, no dear not show any error! but just not update UI! can you help me?